# Python: If error occur then how to go try bock again without executing further

Tags: python, try-catch

Suppose I have the containing try and except command:

```
try: #1
  #do something
except:
  # jump to the try block 1 
try: #2
  #do something
except:
  # again jump to the try block 1
```

here if there is any error in try block it should go to the except block and again jump to the try block.
And if I have two try-except block and the error occur in second try block then it should jump to the try block 1 again.
please help me...

Comment: Will the reason for the failure in `try: #1` be gone away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this,

```
def f():
    try: #1
      #do something
    except:
        f()
      # jump to the try block 1
    try: #2
      #do something
    except:
        f()
```

Note : This will result in infinite recursive loop unless you dont handle it

Answer (score 4):

```
while True:
    try: #1
        #do something
    except:
        # jump to the try block 1 
        continue
    try: #2
        #do something
    except:
        # again jump to the try block 1
        continue
    finally:
        break
```